# Output of command to list using Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm writing an automation script, where it needs to run a command and the output of command should be captured as a list.

For example:

```
# ls -l | awk '{print $9}'
test1
test2
```

I want the output to be captured as a list like `var = ["test1", "test2"]`.

Right now I tried  this but it is saving as string instead of list:

```
# Filter the tungsten services
s = subprocess.Popen(["ls -l | awk '{print $9}'"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
service_state = s.read()
```

Please guide me if anyone has any idea to achieve this.

Comment: just use `s.read().splitlines()`

Comment: use `shlex.split()` on your command string; unless you want some bugs in your software.

Comment: I wouldn't parse `ls -l` if you don't need to http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.  You can use globbing with `*` to expand all files and directories in the current directory. e.g. `echo *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
service_states = s.read().splitlines()
```

but note that this is brittle: File names can contain odd characters (like spaces).

So you're probably better off using `os.listdir(path)` which gives you a list of file names.

Comment: @SwaroopKundeti: Then you might want to accept the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I dint know how to accept the answer, Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can post-process the string according to your needs.

`string.splitlines()` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) will break the string into a list of lines.

If you need to split the results further, you can use `.split()`.

Answer (score 0):

No needed for subprocess:

```
a, d , c = os.walk('.').next()
service_state = d + c
```